# getting problem when I using geolocator in my project

Tags: flutter

I added Geolocator dependency in my flutter project. But when I going to run my app I get this problem->

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':geolocator'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':geolocator:classpath'.
   > Could not download builder-3.5.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar'.
            > dl.google.com
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':geolocator' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

This is my main.dart file->

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: LoadingScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

loadingScreen.dart file->

```
    class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();

}

    class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
      void location() async {
        Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
        print(position);
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: GestureDetector(
          child: Text('pressed!'),
          onTap: () => location(),
        ));
      }
    }
```

What goes wrong here?
Thanking you

Comment: What is your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: any solution on this?!

Answer (score 1):

Delete `pubspec.lock`, restart and run `Pub get` again.

Comment: I did whatever you told but my problem is not resolved.